# How to update day part of date in datetime column

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper

I want to just update the day part of a date for all the records in table. For example if the date is `16-AUG-18`. I want to just update the day that is `16` to `15`. There are data in that particular column like:

- `16-AUG-16`
- `16-AUG-17`
- `17-AUG-18`
- `16-AUG-19`
- `17-AUG-20`
- `17-AUG-21`

I want to update just the day and make it like:

- `15-AUG-16`
- `15-AUG-17`
- `15-AUG-18`
- `15-AUG-19`
- `15-AUG-20`
- `15-AUG-21`

I am using oracle 12C as database. And the dates are in format of `DD-MON-YY`

Comment: You mean that you simply want previous day.

Comment: No, there can be any day. I want to make all as `15`

Comment: Use proper date format, YYYY-MM-DD. (Does 16-AUG-17 mean 2016-08-17 or 2017-08-16?)

Comment: It's in `DD-MMM-YY` formate. So `16-AUG-17` mean 16th August 2017

Comment: @DK Ansh Oracle date columns *don't have a format*; that's just what you see when the results of a query are converted for display. As has been said, avoid using `YY` as it is ambiguous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a quick play on a test table I created.

```
create table table_a 
(col1 date);

insert into table_a
(col1)
values
(trunc(sysdate));

insert into table_a
(col1)
values
(trunc(sysdate + 10));

insert into table_a
(col1)
values
(trunc(sysdate - 10));


commit;

select * from table_a;

The select below shows how to set the day to the 20th of the month

select 
col1 target_date,
col1 + (20 - to_number(to_char(col1, 'dd'))) changed_date,
20 - to_number(to_char(col1, 'dd')) factor_to_add
from table_a;

select * from table_a;

TARGET_DA CHANGED_D FACTOR_TO_ADD
--------- --------- -------------
07-FEB-19 20-FEB-19            13
17-FEB-19 20-FEB-19             3
28-JAN-19 20-JAN-19            -8
```

To employ this in an update statement use

```
update your_table
set your_column = col1 + (20 - to_number(to_char(col1, 'dd')));
```

And obviously -  change the number 20 to whatever day of the month you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

**One option** is to update them one-by-one, such as

```
update your_table set
  date_column = case when date_column = date '2016-08-16' then date '2016-08-15'
                     when date_column = date '2016-08-17' then date '2016-08-15'
                     else date_column
                end;
```

I have no idea what your dates represent (what is a *day* and what is a *year* in, for example, `16-AUG-19`); you should specify that.

**Alternatively**, if possible, you could *calculate* a new date as

```
update your_table set
  date_column = trunc(date_column, 'mm') + 14
where date_column in (date '2016-08-16', date '2016-08-17');
```

- `TRUNC` with the `mm` format mask returns first-day-of-that-month.
- adding 14 (days) to the first day would return 15th of that month

For example:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy';

Session altered.

SQL> select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + 14 result from dual;

RESULT
----------
15.02.2019
```

Comment: First solution will not work. But quite impressed with second solution.

Comment: But will this second solution will work with mine, as the date format is `DD-MMM-YY`

Comment: Well, the first solution *would* work, but it would be a tedious job. If the second one satisfies you, even better.

Comment: As of DD-MON-YY: if column datatype is DATE, then yes - it'll work, no problem. DD-MON-YY is just how you *see* that date.

Answer (score 0):

I used like:

```
UPDATE <Table_Name> SET DATE_COLM = CASE extract(DAY FROM DATE_COLM) WHEN 16 THEN DATE_COLM-1 WHEN 17 THEN DATE_COLM-2 END WHERE extract(MONTH FROM DATE_COLM) = 8 AND extract(DAY FROM DATE_COLM) > 15;
```

But some how i am not happy with this query. I am just looking for more efficient query.

Answer (score 0):

very simple

```
update your_Table
set date_column= date_column-1;
```

Comment: First see and understand the requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple. Since your day (15) is guaranteed* to be present in every month, it should be safe to just replace the date with a literal 15, e.g.:

```
update mytable
set mydate = to_date( '15-' || to_char(mydate,'MM-YYYY'), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
where to_char(mydate,'DD') != '15';
```

Warning: this update will truncate any time portion (at least, for those rows that are not already on the 15th of the month).

* *p.s. this is not technically true for all month days; 29, 30, 31 are not present in every month; and in September 1752 the month did not have days 3 to 13 (the Gregorian calendar skipped from the 3rd to the 14th).*